# where is 'property manager' in visual studio 2010 ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Im trying to run opencv project in vs2010. While configuring vs, I have to work with property manager window. But i'm unable to find property manager window anywhere in view menu or in menu>>other windows menu also. Also, I tried a solution from stack overflow: "Tools>>Customize" menu and reset all. I failed in all three. So, please any one help me how to unhide property manager window??

Thankyou.

Comment: Press `F4` - it opens the `Properties` window - is this what you mean? Or if you mean project properties that just doubble click on the `Properties` _folder_ of your project.

Comment: Pretty unlikely you are using the correct menu commands, it is View > Other Windows > Property Manager.  You can add it, Tools > Options > Customize, Command tab, Menu bar radio button, "View | Other Windows".  Add button, select View + Property Manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the properties of any control then simply select that control and press `F4` to view it's properties.

If you want to change the default language of your Visual Studio then go to:

Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Import Selected Environment Settings... -> Make selection whether to save current settings or overwrite -> Select your new default language.

Comment: I want to work with property sheets. I'm unable to find property manager window. Please help me how to find it. I tried the above options but failed.

Comment: Property Manager should be under the "View" menu or "View > Additional Windows" of your VS.

Comment: Sorry unable to find. Having menu options like: Team Explorer, Architectural Explorer, Sol explorer, Source control explorer, History, Pending charges, Output, Call hierarchy, Start page, Find results, Other windows, Tools bar, Full screen, Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

It is at the very bottom of the Visual Studio View menu, just above Property Pages:
[image]